# Refresh browser window using JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to refresh the browser window using the following code:

```
window.location = window.location.href;
```

but it doesn't refresh the window, however when I try to do this:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

It does redirect me to Google. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Why doesn't it refresh the browser window?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `window.location.reload()`, it does exactly that.

Comment: Also, I would use window.location.reload(true); so that the page is not refreshed from cache - it isn't needed always but sometimes it fixes issues :)

Comment: Just as a side note, the `window` object is actually applied implicitly in Javascript and is thus not needed as long as you don't define a new `location` object in local scope (i.e `location.reload()` will work just as well).

Comment: @Kristijan Judging from the docs, the boolean to trigger a noncached reload is not part of the spec. Or is it by now? Any info on the support for this? This sure is a nice thing to have.

Comment: @MildlyInteresting You are right! :) The current spec doesn't specify this attribute but it is cross browser compatible (speaking about major browsers). Link to specification: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-location-reload

Answer (score 3):

`location.reload(forceGet)` can do the trick. Also, you can set the parameter forceGet to `true` so that it reloads the page from the server and not from the browser cache. Doing this solve me some issues with IE11 and Edge. By default (`location.reload()`) will reload from the cache.

Read: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

In the past I did something like `window.location = ''` to refresh the current page but faced issues (wasn't getting the complete url) with Edge and IE 11 even though it worked well on all other major browsers. So I eventually used `location.reload(true)` to get to work on Edge.

Comment: This question is 3 years old and you repeated the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can even use `location.reload();`

Comment: No need to use a function for something that exists.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the following is the best one

```
window.location.reload()
```

Also we can make it like,

```
window.location.href = window.location.href
```

the second one is getting the current location and assigning the location as current location :)